# QGraphicsScene::addLine. Изменить масштаб не меняя толщины линии

Tags: c++, qt

Рисую множеством линий определенные фигуры на GraphicsView. Мне надо уменьшать и увеличивать всю сцену, но при этом необходимо оставить неизменной толщину линии. Когда делаю так, как в данном примере на линии, то линия становится почти невидимой. Нужно, чтобы она всегда была одной толщины. Может, кто подскажет или наведет на правильное решение этой задачи?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
                       QMainWindow(parent),
                       ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
                       scene_(new QGraphicsScene())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene_);
    scene_->addLine(0, 0, 300, 100);
    ui->graphicsView->scale(0.1, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Немного сбоку от темы вопроса - если рисовать полилинию из кучи отдельных линий, много раз вызывая `addLine`, производительность будет очень плохая. Лучше рисовать через `QPainerPath/QPolygon`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно рисовать объект пером с проставленным атрибутом Cosmetic. В вашем случае приблизительно так:

```
QPen pen;
pen.setCosmetic(true);
scene_->addLine(0, 0, 300, 100, pen);
ui->graphicsView->scale(0.1, 0.1);
```